# Распределение на плоскости С++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

Задача такая: создать генератор случайных чисел конгруэнтным методом(уже сделал) и вывести графическую характеристику(распределение на плоскости(элементы попарно обрабатываются как точки с координатами x и y)). Именно с этим и возникла проблема, не могу найти решения как реализовать это распределение. Я так понимаю это нужно создать график, но как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ось X отвечает за случайные числа (rand()%n).
Ось Y отвечает за частоту выпадения какого то числа (arr[i].count).
Создай массив максимальный индекс которого равен максимальному числу рандомного числа, который может принимать значение int count, после этого с помощью цикла сделай что то вроде:

```
while(true){
X=rand();
Y[X].count+=1;
}
```

Получится распределение по частоте выпадения.

Comment: Это я понимаю, но как мне реализовать график на с++, мне нужно вывести все эти точки на графике в файл

Comment: @ВладиславКарпенко Поищи в интернете библиотеки для визуализации данных. Данные у тебя уже имеются, надо только освоить функции для вывода этого самого графика. С С++ я никогда не работал поэтому ничего посоветовать не могу. В голову вот что приходит: Создай двумерный массив, пройдись с помощью цикла по всему массиву, в каждой итерации с помощью if проверь на содержание "точки", если содержит вводишь данные, если нет то пропускаешь или присваиваешь 0. После этого с помощью обычного двойного цикла пройдись по массиву и выводи как тебе удобно на консоли, ставь пробелы чтобы было ровно.